# GridViewColumn image based on condition

Tags: wpf, listview

So i have this `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Checksum">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="18" Height="18" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.ico"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

**My class**

```
public class MyData
{
    public bool IsOK {ger; set;}
}
```

So i want to bind my `bool` property:

```
`DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsOK }"
```

And i want to display specific `image` for true`and specific`image` for false.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [DataTrigger](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/).

```
<GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Checksum">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="myImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/true.ico"/> 
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="myImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/false.ico"/> 
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Trigger>
            <Image Width="18" Height="18" x:Name="myImage"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

---

I can't test it right now and I see some stuff that can go wrong with this solution, since I don't remember the answers by heart:

- can you set the source value with just a string in a trigger?
- can you reference an element by its name in a datatemplate?

But basically, the answer is DataTrigger. Or a converter that would take IsOK and return an image depending on the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IValueConverter` like this:

```
public class BoolToPathConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string TruePath
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = "DefaultTrueImagePath";

    public string FalsePath
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = "DefaultFalseImagePath";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            bool val = (bool)value;

            return val ? TruePath : FalsePath;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

In the end u will have something like this:

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <!-- local: is the xmlns namespace of the converter  -->
        <local:BoolToPathConverter x:Key="BoolToPathConverter" TruePath="MyTruePath" FalsePath="MyFalsePath" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=IsOk, Converter={StaticResource BoolToPathConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Please don't link to any important part of the answer. External links don't last forever. A trivial demonstration of that converter would improve this answer considerably.

Comment: Ok i will edit it. Thanks for the advice. Can I use stackoverflow links of my own answers?

Comment: Do you mean it's your blog? There's still no guarantee it'll be around.

Comment: From another Stackoverflow answer mate

Comment: Oh, yeah, as long as SO is here, it tautologically isn't going anywhere. Unless the other question gets deleted. Still rather see the text in the answer though. It's always better to see the whole thing in front of you than have to click through for part of it. Thanks for the update!